# Me va a gustar?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Why should I say “me va a gustar” if asking am I going to like it instead of “me voy a gustar”?

Google translates the first as I mentioned and me voy a gustar as I’m going to like it.  Can I use either with appropriate intonation or are they not interchangeable?

Answer (score 6):

*Gustar* is special kind of verb (there is a good handful of others that work the same).

The best way to think of it is: *[something] is pleasing to me*. The *[something]* is the subject of the verb, and the person to whom it is pleasing is the object.

The direct object pronouns are *me, te, le, nos, os, les*.

In the verbal periphrase *ir a [infinitivo]*, the verb *ir* is conjugated with the same subject as the main verb, the infinitive, would be.

In the phrase *Te gusta el pollo frito*, the subject is *el pollo frito*. Word for word, it's like "to you is pleasing fried chicken".

If we say the same phrase in the future, *el pollo frito* will still be the subject, giving: *Te* **va** *a gustar* **el pollo frito**.

The person who likes the thing is always expressed with the direct object pronoun and the thing being liked is always the subject, meaning that *gustar* **is always conjugated in the third person when the thing being liked is an inanimate object**.

*(Yo) me voy a gustar* means "I will like myself"

**Tú** *me* **gustas** = I like you (*you to me are pleasing) // **Tú** *me* **vas** *a gustar* = I will like you

**Yo** *te* **gusto** = You like me // **Yo** *te* **voy** *a gustar* = You will like me

Comment: I don’t disagree with anything you write here, but is it really a special kind of verb? It seems like it’s straightforwardly a verb equivalent to the English verb “please,” and it is only rendered confusing to English speakers because we tend to say “I like that” rather than “that pleases me.”

Comment: The reason I say it's different is because, even though it's not a passive verb, the speaker is not the subject. I only explained it that way because it seems like, in general, it's a concept that is hard for (some) English speakers to grasp, especially in the beginning stages, when it is most likely that they are translating in their head before speaking. (It seems to be especially hard when the subject is not an object in the 3rd person, as in: *A mis padres les gustas*, or in perifrasis, i.e. *A mis padres les vas a gustar*, as was the case for the OP

Comment: I suppose so. I can remember my high school Spanish teacher insisting that "te gusto" was never a correct phrase to use. But in principle there isn't a real difference between "me gusta" and, e.g., "me asusta", I don't think.

Comment: Weird that your teacher would insist that, since *Te gusto* is perfectly grammatical. You're right that *gustarle* and *asustarle* are very similar. That said, English speakers don't find it odd that *Me asusta* means "It scares me", but they do find it weird that *Me gusta* means "I like it" since the construction is the opposite as it is in English. If some don't, great; but the fact is that it is one of the stickier points of basic Spanish grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The subject of the verb *gustar* is the thing that is liked, not the person that feels the liking.

I think the confusion stems from the fact that you are involving a verbal periphrasis, i.e. *ir a* + infinitive, which is used for the future. Go back one step. If you want to say “I like it”, the simplest way is *“Me gusta”* (this is the present simple tense). The subject is the thing (“it”) that you like. The indirect object is the person who does the liking (“I”), in the form that corresponds to an indirect object: *me*.

The verb *gusta* is in the third person singular, because it has to agree with its subject, and its subject is an unspecified “it”. In Spanish you can drop the subject pronoun when unneeded, so you do that. If you wanted to be specific, you could say *“**Eso** me gusta”* (“I like **that**”). Often, with *gustar*, the subject goes after the verb: *“Me gusta eso”*. You can replace *eso* with a noun phrase: *“Me gusta la pizza de tomate”*. And so on.

If you change the tense, the verb changes but is still third person. In the preterite you say *“Me gustó”*, in the imperfect *“Me gustaba”*, etc. Now, if you want to use the *ir a* + infinitive construction for the future, *gustar* will be the infinitive but the conjugation is the same, now shifted to the auxiliary verb *ir*. So *gusta* (3rd person singular, present tense) will become *va a gustar* (with *va* = *ir* in the 3rd person singular).

*“Me voy a gustar”* is wrong (for this meaning) because *voy* implies *yo*: it's a 1st person singular verb. This is not what you want, unless you mean “I'm going to like myself”. The “I” in the English sentence is the 1st person singular implied in the conjugation of *voy*.

Comment: I agree that could cause confusion. In fact, I put/entered [Me voY a gustar, me vA a gustar, me vaS a gustar, me vaN a gustar] into Google Translate to see what it would come up with and was translated to the following: [I'm going to like it, I'm going to like it, I'm going to like it, I'm going to like it] so it shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: @cocteau I've found that Google Translate is fine for well-structured longish sentences and even better for whole paragraphs. It's really not good for smaller sentences or phrases because lack of context confuses it. If you add some filler to those bits you fed it, it gives more acceptable results (although *Me voy a gustar* puzzles it still).

Answer (score 2):

The **direct object** is the person(s) or thing(s) that receive the action of the verb. When the verb "ir" is conjugated in the **3rd** person present ("*va*") and it's accompanied by the pronoun "me" the direct object is another person or thing.

- "**Me** va a gustar" means that you think there's something/someone you're going to like. ¿**Qué** **me** va a gustar? R. Esto/Eso/Ella/Él/Esa cosa.

But instead the **indirect object** indicates who is the receiver of the consequences of the verb.

- "No **le(s)** voy a gustar" means you think not everyone will like you or that someone won't like you. ¿**A quién** no **le/les** voy a gustar? R. A él/ella/ellos.

So when the verb "ir" is conjugated with the **1st** person present ("*voy*") accompanied by the pronoun "me," then **that person** is the subject of the action.

- "No **me** gusto" means you think you're not happy with yourself. Another way of saying this is: "No me agrado/No estoy conforme conmigo mismo/a". ¿**A quién** no le gusto? R. **A mí mismo/misma**.
- "No **me** voy a gustar" means you think you're not going to be okay with yourself. It would be better to say: "No **me** voy a reconocer/No voy a poder mirar**me** a la cara". ¿**A quién** no voy a poder mirar al espejo si lo hago? R. **A mí mismo/misma**.

Comment: Thanks.  I’m sort of ok with the direct object pronoun thing.  I’m still confused in regards to my question though.  In this case i’m trying to work out the difference between; 
Me va a gustar vs 
Me voy a gustar

I saw written ¿me va a gustar? = am I going to like it? My limited knowledge thinks this means “is he/she/it going to like me”
Why isn’t it just ¿me voy a gustar? With appropriate intonation at the end for a question?

Comment: As I said above, the thing being liked is the subject, meaning that *ir* has to be conjugated in the 3rd person. *Me voy a gustar* means **I** *am going to like* **myself**. It is NOT the same as *Me* **va** *a gustar*, regardless of your intonation. That's just the way Spanish is. Resistance is futile 

Comment: @Greg Lamb Well, to begin with, "¿Me voy a gustar?" sounds weird and self referential. Second, if you still don't get it, when someone says "¿Me voy a reconocer/querer en el futuro?" they are referring to themselves and not to another person or thing. It's like someone who looks at his face in a mirror.

Comment: @Greg Lamb The grammatical explanation for *Why isn’t it just ¿me voy a gustar? With appropriate intonation at the end for a question?* is explained by the answers given. Practically, it might help you overcome your confusion if you think about the effect putting the subject first has, that is *¿va a gustarme?* instead of *¿me va a gustar?*. Using that theoretical word order *¿voy a gustarme’* sounds very weird indeed, making the grammatical error stand out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the input.  I got a simple answer elsewhere that made it click.

Basically I have to think "*It* is going to be liked by me?" Instead of "am I going to like it?"

Comment: It is going to be liked by me = Me va a gustar // I like to be liked = Me gusta agradar // You can’t be liked by everyone = No puedes agradarle a todos // The more I know me, the less I like me // I will like myself = me gustaré(a mí mismo) || "Me voy a gustar" is awkward in the active voice, so it'll be even more in the passive.

Comment: Basically, you have to remember the grammar and not try to translate word for word from English :-)

Comment: @cocteau I have an awkward feeling what me voy a gustar sounds like to a native ear :D